# Hide span using jQuery

Tags: jquery, hide, html

How to hide span if there is no text even though there already is an embedded image?
Basically there are little web icon and video icon embedded like this in each span..

Visit website(webicon)     View Video(videoicon)
so if ----no link text---(EMBEDDED WEBICON), the whole thing including the image icon should hide..

```
<div class="profile-links">
     <!--visit website,watch video links-->
     <span class="website"><SharePointWebControls:UrlField FieldName="VISIT WEBSITE" runat="server">
     </SharePointWebControls:UrlField></span> <img class="website" src="/Style Library/Images/design/icons/icon-www.png" alt="WebSite" />
     &nbsp;&nbsp;
     <span class="video"><SharePointWebControls:UrlField FieldName="WATCH VIDEO" runat="server">
     </SharePointWebControls:UrlField></span><img src="/Style Library/Images/design/icons/icon-video-teal.png" alt="Video" />                                                    
</div>
```

Comment: so if ----no link text---(EMBEDDED WEBICON), this span should be hidden

Answer (score 15):

This will hide all of the span elements with a class of 'website':

```
$(function() {
    $('span.website').hide();
});
```